# meaning of "sucklings of the muses"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across this phrase from an article talking about opera goers in the old times. It says only a few of them were true connoisseurs. Then it goes:

“several clerics, several shopkeepers, several schoolboys, sucklings of the muses and soldiers just returning from or about to leave for a tour of duty,” as a nineteenth- century Parisian described this rare breed.

What are "sucklings of the muses"? I looked up the dictionary for "scukling" and "muse", but still can't figure out what it means.

Answer (score 4):

A *suckling* is a baby still at his mother's breast.

The *Muses* were the nine semi-divine inspirers of the arts in religion and poetry of ancient Greece.

A *suckling of the muses* is thus someone who draws his literal and figurative nourishment from the arts, a professional (or would-be professional) artist—in the case of opera-goers probably mostly composers and poets.

Comment: as always...bullet through the brain! :)